# Python 2: Comparing a unicode and a str

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, python-2.x

This topic is already on StackOverflow but I didn't find any satisfying solution:

I have some strings in Unicode coming from a server and I have some hardcoded strings in the code which I'd like to match against. And I do understand why I can't just make a `==` but I do not succeed in converting them properly (I don't care if I've to do str -> unicode or unicode -> str).

I tried `encode` and `decode` but it didn't gave any result.

Here is what I receive...

```
fromServer = {unicode} u'Führerschein nötig'
fromCode = {str} 'Führerschein nötig'
```

(as you can see, it is german!)

How can have them equals in Python **2** ?

Comment: Why not hardcoding it in unicode also in code? `fromCode = u'Führerschein nötig'` instead of `fromCode = 'Führerschein nötig'`?

Comment: Hahaha, yeah of course that's not bad, is a solution, of course.... :DD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tested on 2.7

for German umlauts latin-1 is used.

if 'Führerschein nötig'.decode('latin-1') == u'Führerschein nötig':
    print('yes....')

yes....
```

Comment: Yes and I get `local = criteria['key'].encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @LaurentMeyer try  compare 'Führerschein nötig'.decode('latin-1') and u'Führerschein nötig'

Comment: I didn't downvote... (I actually even upvoted). Thanks it solved it! Much trickier than it looked like...

Comment: @LaurentMeyer I never suspected you Laurent :). There are people who do not know what umlaut is and they are just envious :) Good thing that now we know how on python 2 compare these two types of string. I guess it would be for you no problem running decode on one of them.

Comment: @LetzerWille,  do you know what your code is doing?

Comment: This would only work if the *source file* is saved in `latin-1` encoding.  If the source file was saved in UTF-8, it would fail.  This is not the solution.  Use a Unicode constant, or if you have a byte string read from a source such as a file or other I/O stream, `.decode` the byte string using its known encoding.

Comment: This is a very fragile solution. For an introduction to Unicode support in Python, read https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html .

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you declare the encoding of your Python source file at the top of the file. Eg. if your file is encoded as latin-1:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

And second, always store text as Unicode strings:

```
fromCode = u'Führerschein nötig'
```

If you get bytes from somewhere, convert them to Unicode with `str.decode` before working with the text. For text files, specify the encoding when opening the file, eg:

```
# use codecs.open to open a text file
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
```

Code which compares byte strings with Unicode strings will often fail at random, depending on system settings, or whatever encoding happens to be used for a text file. Don't rely on it, always make sure you compare either two unicode strings or two byte strings.

Python 3 changed this behaviour, it will not try to convert any strings. `'a'` and `b'a'` are considered objects of a different type and comparing them will always return `False`.